# Nosetests execution with different Python versions?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, directory, python

I'm having trouble with Python 2.7 & 3.5.  Right now I use GIT to acquire repositories and their python folders all have 2.7 syntax.

The problem: When i'm attempting to Automate using repositories, my .local/bin nosetests first line of code shows:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
```

so, it checks for

```
.local/lib/Python3.5/site-packages/nose
```

Nowhere to be found is a Python 2.7 folder with similar directories to Python 3.5.

So I will always get a syntax error, as its checking my repositories Python coding, and since they are not Python3 syntax, it will give me errors.  I checked using command

```
python -v
python3 -V
```

and indeed have 2.7 and 3.5 installed.

So I just need guidance/help on how to just gain Python 2.7 site packages with nosetests, so I can automate correctly using the same version as the repositories python.  If I left out anything, I will try my best to fill in the gaps/add more details.  I will of course troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Nowhere to be found is a Python 2.7 folder with similar directories to Python 3.5.

First, uninstall nosetests for python 3 with `pip3 uninstall nose`.
Then install nosetests for 2.7 with `pip2.7 install nose`.
After you do this, the default nosetests should be for python 2.7.

You may want to look into the default python for your project to python2.7 by using virtualenv.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the reply.  I will be gone for a while, will respond with update later.

Comment: Update - Thanks: I was able to just do 'pip install nose' & 'pip install selenium'.  When I executed the automation, it was able to read from Python 2.7, but now I have different errors, but its something on my end that I will attempt to fix.  If I don't fix it in 8 hours or so, i'll create a new topic.  Thanks though for your suggestion :).